# Poisson process/probability

Tags: poisson-distribution

Calls are distributed according to Poisson process at an average rate of 12 calls per hour. Calls are usually handled at the basic sales level, but if there is a more complicated case, the manager will need to be involved.
The probability that an incoming call will require a manager is 0.5 and it is independent of the other calls. 
What is the probability to receive at least one call in 10 minutes time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P(at least one call)= 1 - P(no calls for manager)
                    = 1 - ((0.5 x 0.2)^0 x e^(0.5x0.2)/0!)
                    = 1 - 0.367879441
                    = 0.632121